# Directus - Unable to query related (One to Many) collection

Tags: directus

Related collections are not returned in GraphQL requests for one-to-many relationship.

I have 2 collections `blog` and `comment` with the following relationship

```
blog     1 --> M  comment
comment  M --> 1  blog
```

The mapping was created using a field `blog_id` in the comment collection. When I query a blog and try to fetch the related comments, I get an error:

Query:

```
{
    blog {
        data {
            title
            comment {
                content
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Error:

```
"message": "Cannot query field \"content\" on type \"BlogItem\". Did you mean \"comment\"?",
"extensions": {
   "category": "graphql"
}
```

The reverse works. I mean when I query comments and the related blog, it works perfectly. Any idea why?

Note: This is on a local set up using the docker-compose yaml sample provided on their website, which connects to a mysql database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug in Directus. Fixed by [this PR](https://github.com/directus/api/pull/1750)